# r compare two objects and replace names with corresponding row number

Tags: r

I'm looking for function which can I use to solve my problem. 
I have got:

nazwy - matrix(1 row and n cols) with the names of samples (as reference matrix)

tab - a data.frame.
for example:

```
Nazwy:
1   At5g
2   At5a
3   A63h
4   Aj89
5   Ae31

Tab:
1   At5g    Ae31
2   Aj89    At5g
3   At5a    0
4   0       0
```

In 'Tab' I want to replace names with the corresponding row number from 'Nazwy'.

```
Result:
1   1   5
2   4   1
3   2   0
4   0   0
```

I use a loop with substring() function for this, but for very big data calculations last long so I'm looking for another solution.
Do you have any ideas?

gosia

Comment: Yes I know, it is similar situation. But in this time I've names, so I have to compare whole name first. I'm looking for function which shorten calculation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match`

```
 res <- Tab
 res[] <- match(as.matrix(Tab), Nazwy[,1], nomatch=0)
 res
 #  v1 v2
 #1  1  5
 #2  4  1
 #3  2  0
 #4  0  0
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 res <- copy(Tab)

 for(j in seq_along(res)){
  set(res, i=NULL, j=j, value=match(res[[j]], Nazwy[,1], nomatch=0))
  }
 res
#   v1 v2
#1:  1  5
#2:  4  1
#3:  2  0
#4:  0  0
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_each(Tab,funs(match(., Nazwy[,1], nomatch=0)))
#  v1 v2
#1  1  5
#2  4  1
#3  2  0
#4  0  0
```

#### data

```
 Nazwy <- structure(c("At5g", "At5a", "A63h", "Aj89", "Ae31"), 
 .Dim = c(5L, 
 1L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), "v1"))

 Tab <- structure(list(v1 = c("At5g", "Aj89", "At5a", "0"),
 v2 = c("Ae31", 
 "At5g", "0", "0")), .Names = c("v1", "v2"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))
```